# Odd-frequency pairing

Tags: superconductivity

What is so interesting in odd-frequency pairing in superconductors ([Tanaka](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4700))? Why is it worth exploring both theoretically and experimentaly?

Comment: In general, the order parameter (and then the anomalous Green's functions) have some antisymmetric symmetries inherited from their fermionic character. Since you have only a few variables (spin, position/momentum and time/frequency) you can classify all the available antisymmetric symmetries by knowing the parity of the Green's function in its variables. That's the idea. I can not really say more, since I never felt such a classification was useful, so I never studied it in details.